# Get ASCII grid from compressed .gz file from URL in R

Tags: r, rcurl, gunzip

I am trying to download and `gunzip` grid files in `ascii` format, compressed to `.gz` files from an [URL like this](https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/annual/summer_days/). I tried to get to the files via `y <- gzon(url("name-of-url")` and then `gunzip(y)`, but for `gunzip` that is an invalid file. If I can decompress the file, I would like to read the `.asc` file with `raster()`

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why unzip does not work on these files, but you can get at the contents as follows:

```
URL = "https://opendata.dwd.de/climate_environment/CDC/grids_germany/annual/summer_days/grids_germany_annual_summer_days_1951_17.asc.gz"
download.file(URL, "grids_germany_annual_summer_days_1951_17.asc.gz")

GZ = gzfile("grids_germany_annual_summer_days_1951_17.asc.gz")
Lines = readLines(GZ, 10)
writeLines(Lines, "grids_germany_annual_summer_days_1951_17.asc")
```

Now you have an ascii text file.